# Service referenced by local variable, yet holds value between function calls

Tags: android, android-intent

I was playing around with services and dialogs, and I got a doubt. *Within* a dialog, I am starting a service like this:

```
  Intent lock = new Intent(getActivity(),AppLockService.class);
            getActivity().stopService(lock);
                getActivity().startService(lock);
```

Now the first time I call the dialog through

```
dialog_name.show(getFragmentManager(), "dropbox");
```

Upon pressing the OK button, the intent is launched. Now later, during the **same** app execution, the dialog is triggered again ( which is according to my code logic -- **nothing wrong here**). The code in the dialog then **stops** the previously triggered intent and **starts** the new intent.

My question is this:

**lock** is a *local intent variable* as per my definition. So how does it know that it has to stop *that* particular service I have triggered here the first time? Would someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to keep track of the service in a variable because Android does it for you.

The way that the OS treats a service is that it will not allow more than one instance of the service be to running at any time.

So at any moment there are 0 or 1 instances of your service. If there are 0, no problem, the OS will ignore the call to `StopService`. If there is 1 instance, it must be the instance you started previously - so it will be stop that one.